# Rust compiler does not expect a mutable reference where a mutable reference should be expected

Tags: rust

We are writing a function to erase a node from a sorted tree in Rust, but are stuck with the Rust compiler complaining that it expects no mutable reference when the called function does need a mutable reference:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/tree.rs:111:17
    |
111 |                 SortedContainer::node_find_parent(&mut Some(node), &age, &name)
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found mutable reference
    |
    = note: expected type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<tree::Node>>`
               found type `&mut std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<tree::Node>>`
```

This is our code snippet in the impl block of SortedContainer (Our tree structure):

```
fn node_find_parent<'a>(parent_option: &'a mut Option<Box<Node>>, age: &i32, name: &String) -> &'a mut Option<Box<Node>> {
    // TODO: implement
    parent_option
}

pub fn find_parent(&mut self, age: &i32, name: &String) -> &mut Option<Box<Node>> {
    &mut match self.root {
        Some(node) => if node.name == *name && node.age == *age {
            self.root
        } else {
            SortedContainer::node_find_parent(&mut Some(node), &age, &name)
        }
        None => &mut None,
    }
}
```

The `SortedContainer::node_find_parent` should return a mutable reference, since the return type is a mutable reference

What are we are doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `&mut match` to `match &mut` solved the problems:

```
pub fn find_parent(&mut self, age: &i32, name: &String) -> &mut Option<Box<Node>> {
    match &mut self.root {
        Some(node) => {
            if node.name == *name && node.age == *age {
                &mut self.root
            } else {
                SortedContainer::node_find_parent(&mut self.root, &age, &name)
            }
        }
        None => &mut None,
    }
}
```